# erlang : placeholder in tuple (or list)

Tags: erlang

I'd like to tidy my Eralng code, I found there're lots of issue following:

A = {Tid, _Tv0, _Tv1, Tv2, Tv3}

Is there any way to clean the code like to be: A = {Tid, SomewayReplace(4)}  ???

**Update1:**

like @Pascal example, Is there any way to simple the code A = {T, _, _, _, _, _} like to be A = {T, SomewayReplace(4)} to replace that 4 symbol _ ???

**update2**

in real project, if some record include many element, I found it force me to repeat writing the symbol _, so I wonder if there is any way to simple it???

Comment: What's your mean? Please say clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writting A = Something means that you try to match A with Something or if A is unbound, assign Something to A. In anycase, Something must be defined.

You can find some shortcut in writting.  For example, if you want to assign the result of a funtion to A, verify that the result is a tuple of 5 elements and assign the first element to T, the you can write:

```
A = {T,_,_,_,_} = f(Param).
```

The meaning of _T is exactly the same as any variable. It just says to th compiler to not issue a warning if this variable is not used in the code. It is frequent in pattern matching when you want to ignore the value of a variable but still keep trace of its meaning.

**[edit]**

It is not possible to write `{T, SomewayReplace(4)}`, but you may use records. A record is a tagged tuple (first element is the atom that identify this record. It is not shorter than placeholder for small tuples, but it is clearer, you don't need to remember the location of the information in your tuple, and it is easier to modify your code when you need to add a new element in a tuple. The syntax will be

`-record(mytuple,{field1,...,fieldx,...}.
...
A = #mytuple{fieldx = T} = f(Param).`

waerning: Records are managed by the compiler, so everything must be known at build time (#mytuple{Fieldx = T} is illegal, Fieldx cannot be a variable).

Comment: yes I know diff between _ and _T, I've updated the problem, did you come up with something???

Comment: Yes, thank you, I just wonder if it's possible to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a record? Then you only match the fields you want to extract. As a by-effect, you make the code easier to debug, since you are forced to name the tuple by having a atom first.